Is there a widget gallery for Shell Toolkit (ST) components?
I'd like to contribute a GNOME Shell extension but I'm struggling with documentation. I found out that I cannot use Adwaita in GNOME Shell extensions, but have to rely on St and Clutter.
While for Adwaita there are several possibilities that help to understand its widgets/components, I am not able to find something similar for St or Clutter.
Just to give you an example of what I am looking for: Adwaita widget gallery. For Adwaita and GTK there even is a Workbench app, where one cannot only see, but also try out and code a bit with the available components.
What I found so far is St in the GJS Docs and some JavaScripts ins the GNOME Shell repository. They are pretty much empty and do not serve more that interface signatures (with some exceptions). Currently I am basically using these sources to understand, what is available and how things work, but it would be awesome to have some documentation incl. visualisation of these widgets/components and what they do.
Is there documentation availble for St, Clutter or ui elements from GNOME Shell that helps me to get a good guidance on how to use these?


Is there documentation availble for St, Clutter or ui elements from GNOME Shell that helps me to get a good guidance on how to use these?

There is no visual guide for either St or Clutter. Clutter effectively has no default visuals at all and although St's widgets are more purposeful, they also do not generally have a default look to present.
Most of the API in St roughly traces the counterparts in GTK3, although there are some concepts from GTK4. There is community-maintained documentation at https://gjs.guide/extensions/, but it also does not have a visual overview.
